# How to hide YouTubePlayerView on Android after video finishes playing

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-videoview

What I need to do is the following, I am using the youtube API to play video, what I want is that when the video finishes playing, I need to hide the youtubeplayerview, it is possible? I have tried it from `youtubeplayerview.setvisibility(View.GONE)` code, but it does not work. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! So we can help you as best as possible, could you let us know what you've tried so far (other than `setVisibility()`) and any example code? Also, take a look at ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get a good idea for what information would be helpful to us.

Comment: I also have a same problem and I think the question is clear. The common way is to use setVisibility, we want to know is there any other way to hide youtubeplayerview ? I tried to set Width/Height to 0 and setAlpha to 0, both throw an error (player not visible). is it possible to temporary hide youtubeplayerview?